# How to insert many2many table into entity

Tags: entity-framework

I have a entity and a many to many table associate with it. Because the many2many table have a nchar field, it can not be mapped to a association in EFv1. Is that possible to create a Entity hold both the original entity and the nchar field? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map such a table, but not as a many to many association with properties, because associations in the EF don't have properties. Instead, you'll have two entities with one to many associations to a third entity representing the association.